# How can I make my table height smaller in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-4

How can I make my table height smaller? I've tried adjusting the height on the `<tr>` through CSS but it seems like the height it's currently using is the smallest it will get. I can make it larger but anything under height: 50px, I don't notice a difference.

Here's my table now. I just want to make the row height smaller to compress the table so it fits on the screen without having to scroll down.

[image: Table Picture]

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Month</th>
                <th scope="col">Overtime Hours</th>
                <th scope="col">Compensation Hours</th>
                <th scope="col">Vacation</th>
                <th scope="col">Personal Hours</th>
                <th scope="col">Sick Hours</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Carry Over</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Allotted</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Starting Total</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Jan</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Feb</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Mar</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Apr</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">May</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Jun</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Jul</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Aug</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <th scope="row">Sep</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Oct</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Nov</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Dec</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Yearly Total</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Balance in Hours</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Balance in Days</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Add the Bootstrap `table-condensed` class to the table? (BS3)

Comment: Read the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/#small-table -- `table-sm` should work

Comment: You can decrease padding of td tags.

Comment: Aye! Table-sm works. Thanks m8!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Accordingly to the Bootstrap docs:**

You can simply use `table-sm` as a complement for your table, to make tables more compact by cutting cell padding in half. It would be like:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
  <thead>
...
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
   ...
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As recommended to be responsive, you can use `.table-responsive{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}` as needed to create responsive tables up to a particular breakpoint. From that breakpoint and up, the table will behave normally and not scroll horizontally.

Example:

```
<div class="table-responsive-sm">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    ...
  </table>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive-md">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    ...
  </table>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive-lg">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    ...
  </table>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive-xl">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I first tried table-condensed. But the above answer is correct.

Comment: this will make the table compact in both dimensions. Is there a simple way to only make it compact vertically (i.e. reduce row height but leave column width as is)?

Answer (score 1):

as you are using bootstrap. you may use `<table class="table table-striped table-sm">` class